# Need simple file comparison without diffing

Tags: c#, windows, diff

I'm running Windows 2008 on my server.

I already use Araxis for diffing and love it. But now I have a slightly more unique use case. I need to do a recursive file comparison between 2 folders on my server in which hundreds of thousands of files exist in both. 99% of the files are the same, I already know this. A few files exist in one folder tree but not the other. I need a fast way to find the "difference files". I tried Araxis already, and because of the massive volume of files, it's just too slow. I suspect Winmerge and others will be similarly slow because they're trying to diff each file, which I don't need.

IMPORTANT: Files do not need to be textually or binarily compared. I'm not looking for diff. I'm looking for a blazing fast comparison of which files exist in one tree and not the other, folder-by-folder. Diff tools are all too slow because they're trying to diff, rather than simply looking for which files exist in one place and not the other. The tool I'm looking for needs only compare file names in each folder and go no deeper.

Speed is paramount and "internal contents diffing" is unnecessary.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this on Windows, but it sounds like you want to create two directory listings and then perform a diff on those. That should be pretty straight-forward and perform well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom tool in c# for this. The full source code is below. It works perfectly and I have now used it several times on my production server. Its only objective is to compare two folder trees and add any files/folders to the destination, that only exist in the source. ***It does not attempt to compare files that exist in both places.*** If a file with the same name exists in both trees, and in the same relative location, it is ignored.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace SyncFolders {
 class Program {
  private static string rootSourcePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootSourcePath"];
  private static string rootDestinationPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootDestinationPath"];
  private static int _itemsSynced = 0;

  static void Main(string[] args) {
   if (Directory.Exists(rootSourcePath)) {
    if (Directory.Exists(rootDestinationPath)) {
     var startTime = DateTime.Now;
     Console.WriteLine("Source: " + rootSourcePath);
     Console.WriteLine("Destination: " + rootDestinationPath);
     Console.WriteLine("You are about to copy any DIFFERENT folders/files from source to destination. Continue?");
     Console.ReadLine();

     DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(rootSourcePath);

     WalkDirectoryTree(source, rootDestinationPath);

     Console.WriteLine("");
     Console.WriteLine("Started at " + startTime);
     Console.WriteLine("Finished at " + DateTime.Now);

     Console.WriteLine("");

     if (_itemsSynced > 0)
      Console.WriteLine("Folders/files added: " + _itemsSynced);
     else
      Console.WriteLine("Everything was already in sync!");

     Console.ReadLine();
    } else {
     Console.WriteLine("Folder not found: " + rootDestinationPath);
     Console.ReadLine();
    }
   } else {
    Console.WriteLine("Folder not found: " + rootSourcePath);
    Console.ReadLine();
   }
  }

  private static void WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo source, string destination) {
   System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
   System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

   files = source.GetFiles("*.*");

   if (files != null) {
    foreach(System.IO.FileInfo fi in files) {
     string fullSourcePath = fi.FullName;
     string fullDestinationPath = fi.FullName.Replace(source.FullName, destination);

     if (!File.Exists(fullDestinationPath)) {
      File.Copy(fullSourcePath, fullDestinationPath);
      Console.WriteLine(fullSourcePath);
      _itemsSynced++;
     }
    }

    // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
    subDirs = source.GetDirectories();

    foreach(System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs) {
     string fullSourcePath = dirInfo.FullName;
     string fullDestinationPath = fullSourcePath.Replace(source.FullName, destination);

     if (!Directory.Exists(fullDestinationPath)) {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(fullDestinationPath);
      Console.WriteLine(fullSourcePath);
      _itemsSynced++;
     }

     // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
     WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo, fullDestinationPath);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo.|xcopy /L /s "directory1\*" "directory2"
```

should provide you with a dir1 different from dir2 list

Comment: I ran this: `echo.|xcopy /L ?s "C:\Temp\folder1\*" "C:\Temp\folder2"` -- and got this error: `Invalid number of parameters`

Comment: `?s` was incorrect - should be `/s`. Probably the `echo.|` is also not necessary - but harmless.

Comment: This doesn't break anymore, but also doesn't work correctly. I added a file deep inside the tree of folder1, ran the command, and it didn't find it. Additionally it emits the path of a file further up that already exists in both places; I want it to only tell me of the existence of files in the folder1 tree that don't exist in folder2.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll need to write a custom program to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a need for something similar, and this batch file is what I've come up with. I'd try it on a small tree first, see how it performs.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

REM Change these drive letters to ones that aren't already in use!
SET subst_letter_one=Y
SET subst_letter_two=Z

REM If exactly two arguments not specified then print help
IF [%1] NEQ [] IF [%2] NEQ [] IF [%3] EQU [] GOTO BEGIN
ECHO Usage: compare-folder [Folder 1] [Folder 2]
ECHO.
ECHO Very basic "exists in one but not in the other" type comparison of folder trees
ECHO Example: compare-folder "D:\somepath" "D:\anotherpath"
ECHO.
ECHO Before first-run, edit the two variables in the head of this batch file 
ECHO with spare drive letters that SUBST can use.
EXIT /B 0

:BEGIN
REM Use the SUBST command to map the two folders to temporary drive letters
SUBST %subst_letter_one%: %1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( ECHO Problem mapping %1 to drive letter %subst_letter_one%. 
ECHO Did you try to map an already-used drive letter?
ECHO Exiting
EXIT /B 1 )
SUBST %subst_letter_two%: %2
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( ECHO Problem mapping %2 to drive letter %subst_letter_two%. 
ECHO Did you try to map an already-used drive letter? 
ECHO Exiting
EXIT /B 1 )

REM Main
ECHO.
ECHO ==================== FOLDER 1 ======================
ECHO.
ECHO Files and/or folders absent from %1 are listed below:
ECHO.

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=:" %%i IN ('DIR %subst_letter_two%:\ /A /B /S /O:N') DO ( 
    IF NOT EXIST %subst_letter_one%:%%i ECHO %%i
)

ECHO.
ECHO ==================== FOLDER 2 ======================
ECHO.
ECHO Files and/or folders absent from %2 are listed below:
ECHO.

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=:" %%i IN ('DIR %subst_letter_one%:\ /A /B /S /O:N') DO ( 
    IF NOT EXIST %subst_letter_two%:%%i ECHO %%i
)

REM Unmap temporary drive letters
SUBST %subst_letter_one%: /D
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( ECHO Problem unmapping letter %subst_letter_one%.
ECHO Exiting
EXIT /B 1 )
SUBST %subst_letter_two%: /D
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( ECHO Problem unmapping letter %subst_letter_two%.
ECHO Exiting
EXIT /B 1 )

ENDLOCAL
```